# How to set Asset's Issuer home_domain?

Tags: assets, stellar.toml

I'm new here. For learning purpose I've issued an asset through laboratory.stellar.org.
Now I'm trying to write the stellar.toml file. Checked with online tool https://stellar.sui.li/toml-check/cryptosilly.com qll is green but 1 warning :

**Warnings:
    [CURRENCIES #0] : (onchain) Issuer GC4SPK4MWJTJZDHCJ56HX4YC5Z7B6C3ZCAW7AGUVQRVFCZA77DQJMISU home_domain not set.**

Anyone can help to solve ?
 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation here: https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0001.md

The home_domain is the domain that hosts the `.toml` file. Serve your toml from the correct domain.

Answer (score 0):

Set the home domain for asset issuer. Domain is where your toml file is uploaded.
You can perform this operation directly from laboratory.stellar:

https://laboratory.stellar.org/#txbuilder?params=eyJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7ImZlZSI6IjEwMCJ9LCJmZWVCdW1wQXR0cmlidXRlcyI6eyJtYXhGZWUiOiIxMDAifSwib3BlcmF0aW9ucyI6W3siaWQiOjAsImF0dHJpYnV0ZXMiOnt9LCJuYW1lIjoic2V0T3B0aW9ucyJ9XX0%3D&network=public

Here is detailed documentation for this:
https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/federation/